# angular ng-repeat inside bootstrap popover data-content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angularjs-directive, popover

Im trying to show a list of usernames but when i hover the icon the popover shows up empty.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('dataContent', function(){
  req = [
    users =[
     {username : 'user1'},
     {username : 'user2'}
   ]
  ];
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     template: '<ul ng-repeat="u in req.users"><li>{{u.username}}</li></ul>'
   } 
});
```

**html**

```
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" popover
               data-toggle="popover"
               data-trigger="hover"
               data-html = 'true'
               data-content="<data-content></data-content>">
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like workarounds, but in this case I didn't have the time, and this accomplished what I needed.

What I ended up doing is:

1. Having the list for my ng-repeat inside my controller, not in my directive.
2. Rename my directive, for some reason dataContent didn't work. So let's call it "users"
3. Have a wrapper initial element with an id that will render my directive, so just: 
   `<users id='wrapper-users' style='display:none;'></users>`
4. Set a 1 second timeout at the end of my controller, once it timesout, I grab the HTML 
   `let grabbedHtml = $('#wrapper-users').html();`
5. Also once it timesout, Generate the popover with Javascript: 
   `$("#element-to-add-popover-to").popover({
                   html: true,
                   placement: 'bottom',
                   content: grabbedHtml
               });`
6. Finally, remove my initial wrapper element, 
   `$('#wrapper-users').remove();`

So your **directive** will look something like this:

```
.directive('users', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<ul ng-repeat="u in users"><li>{{u.username}}</li></ul>'
    }
});
```

Your controller:

```
 .controller("myController",
    [
        "$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout) {

            $scope.users = [
                { username: 'user1' },
                { username: 'user2' }
            ];

            $timeout(function() {
                    var grabbedHtml = $('#wrapper-users').html();


                    $("#myI").popover({
                        html: true,
                        placement: 'bottom', //change to whatever you need
                        trigger: 'hover',
                        content: grabbedHtml
                    });

                    $('#wrapper-users').remove();

                },
                1000);

        }
    ]);
```

And in your html file:

```
 <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">

    <users id='wrapper-users' style='display: none;'></users>

    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" id="myI"></i>
</div>
```

I hope this helps. It solve my problem which was exactly the same as yours, I needed an angular ng-repeat as the content of my bootstrap popover.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a new directive:

```
angular.module('Your-Module-Here').directive('popover', function () {
    return function (scope, elem) {
        elem.popover({
            trigger: 'hover'
        });
    }
});
```